# How do banks determine when to ask for two factor authentication?

Tags: authentication, cookies, multi-factor, banks

I was playing around with trying to figure out how my bank knows when to give me a two factor authentication prompt. I had originally thought it was based on my cookies and maybe my IP address. But the results have baffled me.

In incognito mode, the bank asks me for a two-factor code every single time. This didn't surprise me because incognito mode doesn't have any cookies, so I would expect it to prompt me.

In normal mode, I went into "Clear browsing data" and cleared away all cookies, cached files, app data, passwords, download history. I cleared EVERYTHING. I browsed to the bank site, logged in and....NO two factor code prompted.

I repeated this many times, with the same results. My guess is they are doing some kind of advanced browser fingerprinting -- something more complicated than cookies.  What do you guys think is going on?

Comment: It sounds like you didn't successfully clear your cookies. Assuming you're using Chrome, what happens when you open developer tools (F12) > Resources > Cookies > select domain. Are there any cookies listed on the right after you clear your cookies and reload the page?

Comment: It's possible your bank is using another method to store data that clearing your browsing data doesn't clear. Something like the evercookie (http://samy.pl/evercookie/). Verizon and other providers did this until recently to track you.

Comment: In the developer tools, the cookies are gone once I delete them. I know that I deleted the cookies successfully.

Comment: Also in the resources tab in developer tools, is there any data left in any of the other sections besides cookies? Such as Local Storage or IndexedDB?

Comment: i think its a browser leaks with webrtc check if your webrtc enabled or not https://www.browserleaks.com/webrtc WebRTC exposes your internal network IP through allows JavaScript to access your local IP, without user interaction this addon on firefox https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/happy-bonobo-disable-webrtc/?src=api can disable webrtc then check again .

Answer (score 2):

I know several banks use "profiling data" from previous logins in order to try to determine the identity of the user based on:

1. Credentials (obviously)
2. Secret question (not all banks use this method though)
3. IP address (Geo Location + time zone) and internet provider
4. The device(s) previously used to communicate with the bank:

   a. Type of web browser, its cookies, plug-ins & add-ons

   b. Screen resolution

   c. Browser dimensions
5. Timestamps range:  Within what range a user generally logs in.

There are more factors than the above list but it is basically a risk engine that determines when two factor authentication should be triggered or not.